# After boot black screen appears

Tags: boot, pantheon-terminal, desktop

There is black screen with login prompt. After typing my credentials I enter terminal and see my files.

How to fix that problem and go back to usual desktop

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1

Manually start Xorg:

```
startx
```

This might successfully start the display server but, more likely, it will fail and give you an error that might help identify the problem.

If an error is thrown which references a particular package that rings a bell (e.g. a recently-installed graphics driver), do an `apt purge` on it and reboot before proceeding to the next step (if still needed).

### Step 2

Remove these configuration files and clear the user cache (Optionally, rename them instead to serve as backup):

```
rm .ICEauthority
rm .Xauthority
rm -rf .cache
```

Then reboot.

### References

Information on what these config files do:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-is-the-xauthority-file
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/439455/what-is-the-role-of-the-iceauthority-file